# How to divided into 4 equal parts horizontal in Layout

Tags: android

I have to create an app like this

http://s22.postimg.org/fhhzngr65/Untitled.png

To create 4 equal parts vertical, I use `android:weightSum="100"`
How to devided into 4 equal parts horizontal (I use LinearLayout and TableRow)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:text="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:text="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:text="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="01" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="02" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="03" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="04" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="11" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="12" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="13" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="14" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/third"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="21" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="22" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="23" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="24" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fourth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="31" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="32" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="33" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="34" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice way to "cheat"

Don't put any weights on your views.  Then put views with height or width ="0dp" and weight = "1" These invisible views will then consume all of the space that your number views aren't taking which will space everything out evenly.  Something like this from a custom toolbar in one of my projects:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/Toolbar"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/ToolbarButton"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_bookopen_white"
            android:text="">
    </ImageButton>

    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/ToolbarButton"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_favourites_add"
            android:text="">
    </ImageButton>

    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/ToolbarButton"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_bulls_eye"
            android:text="">
    </ImageButton>

    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/ToolbarButton"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_search"
            android:text="">
    </ImageButton>

    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/ToolbarButtonRight"
            android:src="@drawable/sc_flip"
            android:text="">
    </ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this definately work 
dont forget to put margin in linearlayout

toplinearlayout vertical divide in four parts using weightSum

linearlayout1 horizontol divide in four parts using weightSum

linearlayout2 horizontol divide in four parts using weightSum

linearlayout3 horizontol divide in four parts using weightSum

linearlayout4 horizontol divide in four parts using weightSum